# Reduction of Benzamide in acidic conditions?

Tags: organic-chemistry

I am going through a mannich type reaction and ended up with my product show in the image. I compared my answer to the answer key but I noticed that the benzamide was reduced completely. I was wondering at what process during the reaction the benazmide was reduced. [image]

Comment: You dropped a methyl group.  You did a mysterious oxidation of a benzyl group to a benzamide. The answer key is reasonable for a Mannich.

Comment: Bn is PhCH2 not PhCO

Comment: ohhhh, i see. Thank you guys for the help

Comment: Bn = benzyl. Bz = benzoyl.